# How to specify a global system property for java applications?

Tags: java, ant, junit, cobertura

I'm trying to integrate [Cobertura](http://cobertura.sourceforge.net) into our test environment to be able to capture code coverage information. The tests are run from ant scripts using `ANT junit tasks`, and there are more than 50 ant script files (build.xml) with one or more junit task definitions.

As per the [Cobertura doc](http://cobertura.sourceforge.net/anttaskreference.html), the junit tests have to be given the path of the cobertura coverage data file through the `sysproperty` nested element of the junit task. What it means to me is that I will need to update all those 50+ files to specify a sysproperty element for the junit tasks, which I plan to do as a last resort.

I'm running my tests in `Linux (CentOS)` and I would like to know if there is a way to specify a global system property `(-Dxxx=yyy)` so that the system property is made available to all java applications running in the system.

-EDIT-
The junit tests are run in a forked JVM. `<junit fork="yes" ...`

Comment: Depending on which ide you use, it should be pretty straightforward to refactor them quickly. Also you can try the ant input task, if that will help.

Comment: @r0ast3d As I'd mentioned, that's the way I'm going to take if I don't find another simple solution which doesn't require modifying the scripts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try to set [ANT_OPTS](http://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html#envvars) environment variable.

---

ANT_OPTS - command-line arguments that should be passed to the JVM. For example, you can define system properties or set the maximum Java heap size here.

---

-EDIT-

You have to set `_JAVA_OPTIONS` environment variable. [Here](http://danielveselka.blogspot.com/2010/11/set-jvm-default-property-with.html) and [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/2d/flags.html) there is some information about it.

Comment: +1 Thanks. It works if I run the tests within the same VM, but I need to run my tests in a forked VM. I have updated the question.

Comment: Just updated my answer. You have to set `_JAVA_OPTIONS` environment variable to define default JVM properties.

Answer (score 0):

alternatively set environment variable and in your ant script use :

```
<property environment="env"/>
<echo>${env.yourEnvVariable}</echo>
...
```

The advantage over using ANT_OPTS (which is primarily meant for ant internal settings, like f.e. VM parameters..) is the possibility for userspecific settings if using user environment variables whereas ANT_ARGS is "static" for all ant scripts.